# Odoo V16 API - Create Payment on account

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

Using Odoo v16, I'm using the API to import legacy data via PHP.
I'm struggling to get the Payment on Account working.

This would be in relation to payments that have NOT been allocated to an invoice.
This is the code I have currently.

```
$payment_id = $odoo->get('account.payment', 'create', array(array(
    'date'                  => date('Y-m-d', $invoice['date']),
    'extract_state'         => 'no_extract_requested',
    'journal_id'            => 8,
    'partner_type'          => 'customer',
    'payment_type'          => 'inbound',
    'partner_id'            => $invoice['partner_id'],
    'amount'                => abs($invoice['amount'])
)));
```

This API call completes successfully. When navigating to the Accounting -> Customers -> Payments, the record is displayed (which I then manually post / approve). Likewise, when viewing Journal Entries I can see the associated record.

But, here lies the problem - the record does NOT appear against the customer when viewing their due balance.

If I manually re-create the record via the Odoo interface, coping all the data, payment is registered and appears against the customer account.

I'm clearly missing some information, just can't figure out what?